# REACT_EDITOR=atom ERR

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My console keeps on saying that 
"To set up the editor integration, add something like REACT_EDITOR=atom to the .env.local file in your project folder and restart the development server. Learn more"

I cant even find the .env file on my create-react-app.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Create-React-App supports [custom environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables).

The documentation discusses how to declare these variables:

> This can be done using two ways: either in your shell or in a .env file. Both of these ways are described in the next few sections.

### Through the local environment

The first way is to add it to your local environment:

For instance, if you're using bash, edit `~/.bashrc`

Add `export REACT_APP_EDITOR=atom` to the bottom then restart your terminal (or `source ~/.bashrc`)

### Through .env files in your application

The second way is to create a `.env` file at the root of your application directory, and add the variable on a single line there:

`REACT_APP_EDITOR=atom`

From the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#what-other-env-files-can-be-used), these types of files can be declared and will be consumed by Create-React-App:

> `.env`: Default.
>   `.env.local`: Local overrides. This file is loaded
>   for all environments except test. 
>   `.env.development`, `.env.test`, `.env.production`: Environment-specific
>   settings.
>   `.env.development.local`, `.env.test.local`, `.env.production.local`: Local
>   overrides of environment-specific settings.

Comment: Why would the warning message specifically mention the `.env.local` file then, if the change should be made to the login shell?

Comment: @BenVoigt I've updated my answer to address the different variations and app specific `.env` files.